# How to use CSS rollover for multiple background images

Tags: jquery, css

Have an image rollover for the background image and since I have several images, I would like to know how to reuse the same #Rollover for multiple images ?

```
<div id="leftprod"><a href="product.php" id="myRollover" ></a></div>


#Rollover {
 background-image: url('images/mood160-1.jpg');
 width: 160px;
 height:207px;

 position: absolute;

}

#Rollover:hover {
 background-image: url('images/mood160-2.jpg');
 width: 160px;
 height:207px;
 border: solid 0px #676767;

}
```

Comment: Its mainly for the hover image, which will keep changing the URL.

Comment: Found what I was looking for here; http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/images/rollovers.html

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you have `<a id="Rollover">`

Change it to use classes instead of an ID like this

```
<a class="rollover">
```

And then you can use this CSS:

```
.rollover:hover {
 background-image: url('images/mood160-2.jpg');
 width: 160px;
 height:207px;
 border: solid 0px #676767;
}
```

This will apply the rollover to anything that has a class of `rollover`

The main difference bteween IDs and classes is you should only use an ID once, as you want to apply a rollover affect to multiple elements, you should use a class.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder though, for the hover, I would still need to have multiple rollover hover statements to change the url for a class

Comment: With this, the same background image appears on every hover ? It needs to somehow dynamically change.

Comment: You would need a separate class for each different background image.

Answer (score 0):

You would typically create a parent element that contains the various images, then have styles like this:

```
#Parent:hover #Rollover1 { background-image: ... }
#Parent:hover #Rollover2 { background-image: ... }
```

This lets you change the rollver when the entire group is hovered over.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to a class instead and apply it as class="Rollover" to all of the images you want to be like this.

```
.Rollover {
    ...
}
```

rather than

```
#Rollover
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `class` instead of `id` and add `class="Rollover"` in all images.

change `#Rollover` to `.Rollover` in your css

Read this nice article:

- [The Difference Between ID and Class](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

Answer (score 0):

Simple we need to change the image id every time the image loaded:

```
<img src="images/icons/button_cancelled_gray.jpg" 
     border="0" 
     id="Image1<?php echo $i +=1; ?>" 
     onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image1<?php echo $k +=1; ?>','','images/icons/button_cancelled.jpg',1)" 
     onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()"
/>
```

So I add a PHP counter with the help of which, but remember I have wrote `Image1` it is for defining image separately, if you use another image simply change it to `Image2`, similarly play with your counter don't use same variable again again, as it will change the id's which have to be similar, or it will make multiple same id which have to be different.